# Javascript onclick put text into an text field

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, button, input, onclick

Hey guys my onClick Event doesn't put the date into the text input field.

```
<input class="span2" id="datum" name="datum" type="date">
<button class="btn" type="button" onclick="datum()">Heute</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function datum() {
    var datum = new Date();
    var tag = datum.getDate();
    var monat = datum.getMonth();
    var jahr = datum.getFullYear();
    var element = document.getElementById("datum");
    element.innerHTML = tag + "." + monat + "." + jahr;
}
</script>
```

Comment: use .value instead of innerHTML. Also add one to the month. JS months are 0 based

Comment: how do you mean that i need to add one to the month?

Comment: Also, you'll need to format the date string as required by the input (i.e. yyyy-mm-dd).

Comment: how can i make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`.
2. Try not to use the same name, id and function name
3. Add one to the month. JS months are 0-based.
4. Pad with leading 0 for a proper date
5. change `type=date` to `type=text` since you want to use a different format

   > [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format) The HTML5 date input specification [1] refers to the RFC3339 specification, which specifies a full-date format equal to: yyyy-mm-dd.

Like this

```
element.value = tag + "." + (monat+1) + "." + jahr;
```

```js
function pad(num) {
  return String("0" + num).slice(-2);
}
function heute() {
    var datum = new Date();
    var tag = datum.getDate();
    var monat = datum.getMonth();
    var jahr = datum.getFullYear();
    var element = document.getElementById("datum");
    element.value = pad(tag) + "." + pad(monat+1) + "." + jahr;
}
```

```html
<input class="span2" id="datum" name="datum" type="text" placeholder="tt.mm.jjjj">
<button class="btn" type="button" onclick="heute()">Heute</button>
```

Comment: It does in my snippet above

Comment: i copied your code but it doesnt work, i think it is something with the javascript snippet...

Comment: There must be something in your page - or your browser does not like the same name, ID and function name - I changed the function name to heute

Comment: @NilsBlaumer thanks for accepting. If your "it does not work" comment is no longer relevant, please delete the comment so other visitors do not think the code fails

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="span2" id="datum" name="datum" type="text" value="<?php echo date("d.m.Y"); ?>" required>
<button class="btn" type="button">Heute</button>
```

I did it with PHP :P

Comment: That just sets the date, then you can drop the button.